# check radiobutton according to the value of row item in dataset

Tags: vb.net

I want to check radiobutton which is depends on value of specific row item in the dataset.

```
Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter _
                                                ("select top 1 * from tbl_party_record order by rid desc", con)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adp.Fill(ds)
    View.TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    View.TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)
```

please consider item3 here as ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).
If value of item3 is male then select radio button male elseif value of item3 is female then select radio button female elseif value of item3 is other then select radio button other.
how can I achieve this?
Thanks guys...

Comment: presumably each of your radio buttons have IDs? Set the Checked property of each one appropriately in your If statement.

Comment: Sorry dear, but that is not my code, I am just explaining what I want to do. Fine, IDs are radiomale, radiofemale, radioother...sorry for my mistake because I am at beginner level, I accept it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is quite straightforward, I think. To set a radio button in ASP.NET you can use the `Checked` property:

```
'First un-check them all.
radiomale.Checked = False
radiofemale.Checked = False
radioother.Checked = False

'Now set the right one checked based on the data
Dim genderValue As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)

Select Case genderValue
  Case "male"
    radiomale.Checked = True
  Case "female"
    radiofemale.Checked = True
  Case "other"
    radioother.Checked = True
End Select
```

If you haven't already, you should also make sure all your radio buttons have the same value for the `GroupName` property, so that the user cannot select more than one radio button at the same time, and also so the value is posted back to the server properly on the next submit.

Comment: Thanks sir, its works for me. Actually I was finding exactly this, but I dont knew how to do this, you make my day sir, Thank You once again.